# Forge server authentication error 2 Legged

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am new to forge. I have been trying to create a basic server and authentication using nodejs by following exact steps in the youtube training videos. But i am facing errors in the initial phase itself getting an error code: ECONNRESET. I have a feeling that my firewall is blocking the servers but not able to make anything concrete out of this. The url that i tried hitting is "http://localhost:3000/api/forge/oauth/token". For some reason it always goes to catch block. Kindly let me know how to debug the error, and figure out the urls that need unblocking if necessary.

Comment: Please share more information about _which_ tutorial exactly you're following (there are **many** of them), and if possible, include the code snippet related to the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Also, to rule out firewall issues, try accessing one of the Forge endpoints from another HTTP client instead of your own code. For example, this [example](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authenticate-POST/#example) shows how you could make a request to the Authentication service from the command-line, using `curl`.